# How to execute a block of code after an element has loaded with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have a list of products in one page, there's a button that appears on hover over every product image. Once you click the button mentioned, a modal slides in (vía ajax). Inside the modal page, there's a Add to cart button, I want to be able to execute a block of code once the Add to cart button is loaded.

This is what I've tried so far:

```
jQuery('body').on("mouseenter",'.one_third', function () {
        console.log('body');
     jQuery(this).children('a.yith-wcqv-button').show().click(function() {
        console.log('quickview');

        jQuery(".single_add_to_cart_button").load(function() {
            console.log('loaded');
        });

     });
 }).on("mouseleave",'.one_third', function () {
    jQuery(this).children('a.yith-wcqv-button').hide();
 });
```

Right now the load event isn't working, but if I do something like the following from the console it does work.

```
jQuery(".single_add_to_cart_button").click(function() {
            console.log('clicked');
        });
```

I'm stuck, and I'm out of ideas of how to approach this problem.

Comment: Well, you can't add a `load` event to a element that hasn't loaded yet. You don't show the AJAX part, but this should probably be handled by the callback in your AJAX call.

Comment: Hi Matt, it's a wordpress admin-ajax.php request, and I'm hoping not to mess with that code, thanks.